# How to back up efficiently (without copying files that have not been changed)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, sync, rsync

I regularly do back ups of files on my laptop using an external hard-drive. I use a command line of a Linux system (Ubuntu). So far I have just copied everything to a directory and have removed the old back up. However, recently I have realized that it is very inefficient since there are only a few changes (differences) between the new state of my directory and the old one. Roughly speaking, I do not need to copy thousands of files if there are only 2 new files and only 3 old files have changed.

So, I wonder how to accomplish the following:

1. Compare the current state of my folder and the "old" state (the one from back up).
2. Copy the new files (those that are in the current folder but not in the back up).
3. Copy those files that have been updated (the files whose modification date-time is after the time of the last back up).
4. If a file is not anymore in the current directory but still in the back up, it should be removed from the back up folder.

So, to summarize, after the desired operation, the content of the back up folder should be identical to the content of the folder that I want to back up. How can I achieve this?

Comment: One of your tags is the answer - use rsync to sync only changed files.  If you want incremental backups, look at rsnapshot.

Comment: So you delete the backup copy of files... and overwrite the backup copy of changed files... You know that isn't really a backup anymore, it's just a more efficient mirror image? The biggest point (IMO) of a backup is being able to go back and see old versions of changed & deleted files. Maybe the title should be edited, I thought you wanted an incremental backup too. (Thanks @davidgo for mentioning `rsnapshot`, interesting! I wonder if it can be combined with squashfs in one step)

Comment: I doubt you can combine squashfs with rsnapshot, it would not make much sense.  rsnapshot uses symlinks to create multiple file trees while keeping only 1 copy of each file, so its fairly efficient.  If you needed something more efficient you would need the underlying block device using zfs or btrfs or some other filesystem I'm unawware of - or maybe use fusecompress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the rsync command.

```
apt-get install rsync
```

Using the -a parameter does what you have outlined.

```
rync -a MyFiles MyBackup
```

If you would like to see what rsync would do without making changes int he destination use the -n option meaning dry run.

```
rync -an MyFiles MyBackup
```

Further there are graphical front-ends to rsync such as `grsync`

Comment: What happens to files that have been deleted from the source? `-a` deletes them from the destination?

Comment: No, you can add the --delete option to do that.